# Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

Why am I getting the exception when I am trying to bind a String Property itself.

I XAML if I write:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
                <telerikData:GroupDescriptor Member="FirstName" />              
</telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
```

This works perfect.

But If I write the following:

```
private string filterType =  "FirstName";

        public string FilterType
        {
            get { return filterType; }
            set { filterType = value; }
        }
<telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
                <telerikData:GroupDescriptor Member="{Binding FilterType}" />               
</telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
```

Then am getting the error!!

```
Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'.
```

Comment: Just FYI, this helped me on WinRT as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the Member property probably isn't a `DependencyProperty`. You can't use a binding on a regular C# property.

**Edit:** It's definitely not a `DependencyProperty`. See: http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/p_telerik_windows_data_groupdescriptor_member.html

Comment: Then how shall I proceed. Is it good idea to create a custom control and then assign the value to the propertey?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-grouping-setting-groups-programmatically.html

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Member` expects a string. So you cannot assign a binding to it.

You can bind a string to a dependency property but not the other way around.